How to resize non-primary disk partitions?
I am transferring from Windows to Linux. Windows was my primary operating system, and that is what is installed on my C:\ drive
I do not intend to remove Windows yet
I have installed Linux on G:\, and gave it 100GB space. I would now like to extend how much space Linux has
I am moving files across from Windows to Linux, drawing on various external hard disks
I have two physical hard drives; disk 0 is 1TB, and disk 1 is 6TB: Disk Manager
The second disk is split into two drives, D:\ and G:\ Windows Explorer
However, I cannot shrink G:\ to give the space to my Linux partition, despite having over 1TB free
Defrag reports 0% fragmentation, so I infer that fragmentation is not the issue
I have read Cannot shrink C: partition: Not enough space , but I do not get the "There is not enough space available on the disk(s) to complete this operation" error
I have read How to shrink Windows 7 boot partition with unmovable files, but Windows Event Log gives me an ID 258, which, unlike ID 259, does not give me any parameters that I can feed into fsutil
I have read How can I shrink my Windows partition further than the disk management is allowing? , but I cannot find any boot files on G:\ (and I would not expect them anywhere but C:\), even with hidden files being displayed
How can I shrink my G:\ drive so that I can give my Linux partition to extra 1TB please?

you say I have installed Linux on G:\, and gave it 100GB space - yet your picture shows that G: is 2.7TB

You also said you installed Linux on G, AND that you're trying to SHRINK G in order to GIVE MORE SPACE to Linux. Your question does not agree with itself yet. Please EDIT it to make your question more clear. Also, what have you looked at on the Linux side?

Can you in two sentences describe exactly what partition you want to expand and which partition you want to shrink? Your 2TB partition (G) only can be expanded by 800MB. The 2TB partition cannot be used to expand a partition that comes after it.  So I am asking for clarification because your current description is confusing. None of the partitions you currently have can be expanded by any of the partitions that currently exist by shrinking them.

Your terminology is inaccurate. C:\  and G:\  (i.e. a drive specification with the backslash) refer to the root directories of filesystems, and are not drives. A (logical) drive in Windows is simply C: or G: (i.e. without the backslash), which exist as partitions.

"I have installed Linux on G:" - That logical-drive/partition has an NTFS filesystem. How did you manage to "install Linux" in an NTFS filesystem? What are you calling "non-primary" partition(s)?
